# How to trigger a sharepoint custom list workflow programmatically

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom-list

I have a custom list and associated workflow with it. It is working fine from within SharePoint, but the workflow is not triggered when new item is added from a WebPart.

I have added `SPWorkflowAssociation` which is also not helping.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
  {
    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
     SPList ListEmployeeNew = web.Lists["CustomList"];
     SPWorkflowAssociationCollection asscoll = ListEmployeeNew.WorkflowAssociations;
     SPListItem newItem = ListEmployeeNew.AddItem();
     newItem["First Name"] = "Fist Name";
     newItem["Last Name"] = "Last Name";
     newItem.Update();
     foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation spwfa in asscoll)
     {
       site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(newItem, spwfa, spwfa.AssociationData);
     }
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: You have to set value for AssociationProperty AutoStartCreate=True

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am getting error as "New instances of this workflow template are currently disallowed."

Comment: @DipenShah Thanks for your help, foreach was taking all the versions of workflow, with the name condition it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dipen Shah for helping to resolve this issue.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
  {
    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
     SPList ListEmployeeNew = web.Lists["CustomList"];
     SPWorkflowAssociationCollection asscoll = ListEmployeeNew.WorkflowAssociations;
     SPListItem newItem = ListEmployeeNew.AddItem();
     newItem["First Name"] = "Fist Name";
     newItem["Last Name"] = "Last Name";
     newItem.Update();
     foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation spwfa in asscoll)
     {
       if (spwfa.Name == "Workflow Name")
       {
         spwfa.AutoStartCreate = true;             
         site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(newItem, spwfa, spwfa.AssociationData);
       }
     }
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
   }
 }
});
```